# Create a even border around a TextView with 1 character

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Desired implementation]

Hello i want to recreate this "design" in a android view. Basically a even sided border around a TextView.

I created a TextView:

```
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="R"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:background="@drawable/border_red"
            android:gravity="center" />
```

And i added a drawable shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#ff687b" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
    <padding android:right="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:top="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

The strange behavior in the android previewer and the app i get this strange behavior:

[image]

I have not defined any paddings yet. They are all set to `0dp` but the border seems to have some kind of margin/padding already.

This behavior make it difficult to create a even rectangle border around the character. :-(

What is the problem, what i'am doing wrong?

Comment: put the textview inside of a linear or relative layout... add padding to that layout.. and then add the border to THAT and not the textview.

Comment: using linear layout as a parent and add the border to it, make no difference than adding the border to the textview

Comment: youre wrong..but ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `android:includeFontPadding="false"` to remove the font padding from the `TextView`

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="R"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:background="@drawable/border_red"
            android:gravity="center" />
```

[image]

This will remove most of the `padding` from the top and bottom of the `TextView`.

To get a perfect square you have to give the fix `width` and `height` to the `TextView`

Comment: @rubiktubik did you try the above solution?

Comment: I tried this solution, it makes it a little better but i still cannot give equal paddings to the border. Using fixed widht and height might be a problem on different screens

Comment: @rubiktubik there's no way of reducing the `TextView` dimensions to the exact pixel-perfect text size.
You have to give fixe size instead of `wrap_content` for the desired result.
And also in the image (R) left and right padding is more than the top and bottom padding. So you can get the result by giving different padding to `top and bottom` and `left and right`.

Comment: this isnt the best solution. see my answer. giving a view a static width and height is not good since there are devices that are smaller/bigger when it comes to dp. i wont downvote for the sack of receiving hate, but this is wrong @PrithviBhola

Comment: @DroiDev I don't get the point of wraping the `TextView` inside the `LinearLayout`. It won't make any difference. And I suggested to give different padding for `top and bottom` and `left and right` which is the required case.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't approve this, that is OK. I am showing you so you learn. :)

Using your same XML as above...

Here is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vzw.www.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/red_border"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="H"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the outcome for this...

[image]

You can also achieve this by creating a custom TextView... but I wont go into that... but if you want, you could. Its a even better solution actually.

Comment: I this case also `top and bottom` and `left and right` padding are not proper. Please check the image of `(R)` in the question, `top and bottom` and `left and right` padding are different. So it is required to give different padding for `top and bottom` and `left and right`.

Comment: then creating a custom view is better, as i started.

Comment: In case of custom view also you will be providing different padding programatically , which is same as giving it in XML. Because if you notice, text height is more than its width, and we require square view, so you have to give different padding.

Comment: not when you work with Paint/Rect/Canvas. you can draw a custom border. I advise you to look into it. you can eliminate the padding completely, find the height, do some math, and calculate proper padding.